# Heroku can't find styles.css

Tags: django, heroku

Trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku for the first time. When I view the app using Django, everything shows up correctly, but when I run it on Heroku, pieces of the UI are missing.

I'm not too familiar with the frontend - this was a group project and I was working on backend - and my team isn't willing to help with deployment, so I'm unable to diagnose any frontend issues.

Looking at the Heroku logs, I get this error "Not Found: /static/styles.css" - but there is a styles.css file under static.

Does anyone know where the root problem might lie?

Under settings.py I have specified this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]
```

All functionalities work as expected, I think it has something to do with the base.html file - but this is just a stab in the dark.

An example of what it's meant to look like, compared to what it looks like on Heroku.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly you need to use something like whitenoise to serve statics on production like servers